# Populate List with Items to show MonthWise in MaterialCalendarView?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-calendar

How the List be Populated with events monthwise through the web.As the Calendar Month be Changed the List Should be refreshed.I am getting all event right now.Can this issue be solved?

**CalenderFragment**

```
  public class CalenderFragment extends Fragment implements OnDateSelectedListener, OnMonthChangedListener {
        String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getEvents";
        String access_token;
        ListView listView;
        com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView calendarView;
        ArrayList<CalenderPojoStudent> student_list_calender = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        List<CalendarDay> calendarDays;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        String y;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calender, container, false);
            getActivity().setTitle("");
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            //   calendar = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
            /*     calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view,
                                                int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });   */

            calendarView = (com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
            //  calendarView.addDecorator(new HighlightWeekendsDecorator());
            calendarView.addDecorator(new OneDayDecorator());
            // calendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator(Color.RED, calendarDays));
            // calendarView.addView(onMonthChanged(calendarView,date));
            // calendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator(Color.RED, calendarDays));
            //calendarView.addDecorator(new MySelectorDecorator(getActivity()));


            // calendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator("#FF0000",student_list_calender));
            //  calendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator("",));
            calendarView.setDateTextAppearance(View.ACCESSIBILITY_LIVE_REGION_ASSERTIVE);
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarView.setSelectedDate(calendar.getTime());


            calendarView.setOnMonthChangedListener(this);
            //  calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(this);


            calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {


                    CalenderAdapter calenderAdapter = new CalenderAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_calender);
                    listView.setAdapter(calenderAdapter);


                    calendarView.setHeaderTextAppearance(R.style.AppTheme);
                }
            });


            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.calenderlist);
            SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getContext());
            session.checkLogin();
            access_token = session.getAccesstToken();
            makeJsonObjectRequest();


            return view;
        }

        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();


        private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
            String URL = Navigation_URL;

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {


                                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String StartDate = jsonObject.getString("StartDate").substring(0, 10);
                                    String Title = jsonObject.getString("Title");
                                    int EventID = jsonObject.getInt("EventID");


                                    //String y = "#" + EventID;
                                    //int z = Integer.parseInt(y);
                                    //int y = Integer.parseInt(("#" + "2493A7"));
                                    // int colorcrop = Integer.parseInt("#2493A7");
                                    // int y = Integer.parseInt("#" + ("2493A7"));


                                    CalendarDay date = new CalendarDay();
                                    y = (simpleDateFormat.format(date.getDate()));
                                    System.out.println(y);
                                    // OnMonthChangedListener onMonthChangedListener=getActivity().;


                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    //  if (y == StartDate) {
                                    student_list_calender.add(new CalenderPojoStudent(StartDate, Title));
                                    // }





                                  /*  try {
                                        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(StartDate);
                                        //   String listofinformation = (EventID);
                                        int color = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(EventID));

                                        try {
                                            // int y = Integer.parseInt("#" + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(color)));
                                            int y = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(color))));
                                            Event event = new Event(date, y);
                                            events.add(event);


                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                                        }

                                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }   */


                                }

                                CalenderAdapter calenderAdapter = new CalenderAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_calender);
                                listView.setAdapter(calenderAdapter);


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
    /*
                            for (Event event : events) {
                                EventDecorator eventDecorator = new EventDecorator(calendarView, event.getDate(), event.getColor());
                                calendarView.addDecorator(eventDecorator);

                                EventDecorator eventDecorator = new EventDecorator(event);


                            }   */


                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return headers;
                }
    /*
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("id", master_id);
                    map.put("accessID", accessID);
                    map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                    return map;

                } */
            };


            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // handle item selection
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    // do s.th.
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(FORMATTER.format(date.getDate()));

            // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Second Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            // CalenderAdapter calenderAdapter = new CalenderAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_calender);
            // listView.setAdapter(calenderAdapter);


            // int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            // int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            //int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            //System.out.println(year);
            //System.out.println(month);
            //System.out.println(day);


            y = (simpleDateFormat.format(date.getDate()));
            System.out.println(y);


            // date = widget.getSelectedDate();


            //widget.setDateSelected(date,true);


            // widget.setShowOtherDates(MaterialCalendarView.SHOW_ALL);

            // System.out.println("date is" + date);


            widget.invalidateDecorators();
            //  makeJsonObjectRequest();
        }


        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
            OneDayDecorator oneDayDecorator = new OneDayDecorator();
            oneDayDecorator.setDate(date.getDate());

            //date = widget.getSelectedDate();
            //Log.d("date","displyed");
            //  widget.addDecorator(new EventDecorator(Color.DKGRAY, calendarDays));


            //  date = widget.getSelectedDate();
            //  System.out.println(date);


            if (selected == true) {
                //It can't be show
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onClick" + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            widget.invalidateDecorators();
        }


    }
```

**JSON**

```
[
 {
    "EventID": 2095,
    "Title": "Holiday",
    "Description": "",
    "StartDate": "2017-06-27T00:00:00",
    "StartTime": "00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2017-06-28T00:00:00",
    "EndTime": "00:00:00",
    "IsFullDay": true,
    "IsHoliday": true,
    "DateTime": null
  },
  {
    "EventID": 2097,
    "Title": "Art Exhibition",
    "Description": "asd",
    "StartDate": "2017-06-28T00:00:00",
    "StartTime": "12:07:00",
    "EndDate": "2017-06-28T00:00:00",
    "EndTime": "17:07:00",
    "IsFullDay": false,
    "IsHoliday": false,
    "DateTime": null
  }
]
```

> How can i Compare to Material Calendar Date to Web Date and Display in
>   monthWise?

Comment: Use ListView to Display the Event.For Event  monthwise use  onMonthChanged() method.

Comment: I have used,ListView Below the MaterialCalendar.Monthly event are not Displayed ,total  events are populated.